# css Position and center for text inside any div is not working

Tags: html, css

I have a Triangle (Drawing using css) and I am displaying a number inside the triangle..
But my number is dynamic (I am getting number different always).

I want number should align center of the triangle for all different values.

My Html :-

```
<div class="triangle-up"><span class="triangle-up-span">125</span>
</div>
<div class="triangle-up"><span class="triangle-up-span">1</span>
</div>
<div class="triangle-up"><span class="triangle-up-span">1255</span>
</div>
<div class="triangle-up"><span class="triangle-up-span">12</span>

</div>
```

My Css:-

```
.triangle-up {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 36px 38px 36px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #d30000 transparent;
    line-height: 0px;
    left:-10px;
    position:relative;
}
.triangle-up-span {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    position:relative;
}
```

[jsfiddle code here](http://jsfiddle.net/tb48r/)

Please guide if I did any silly mistake..

Comment: I checked http://jsfiddle.net/KtVAt/2/ But not sure how to use in this

Comment: Try to add the triangle to a pseudo-class instead. It will be hard to get the text positioned right with `width: 0;`

Comment: You cannot put content in something that has no height & width dimensions and you cannot put content in borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/tb48r/2/)**</kbd>

Add below properties to `.triangle-up-span`

```
width : 38px;
/* equal to triangle bottom width */
margin-left : -19px;
/* equal to negative of half of triangle bottom width/width of .triangle-up-span */
```

Here is the changed css of `.triangle-up-span`

```
.triangle-up-span {
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    position:relative;
    width: 38px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -19px;
}
```